# SQLite linked table in Access gives #Deleted values only after inserting a new value

Tags: sqlite, ms-access, odbc

In MS Access (Office 365) I'm using the [SQLite ODBC driver](http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/) (0.9996) to link to a table in an SQLite 3 database.

**Problem**

When I open the linked table it can display its contents, but after I insert a new entry to the table it displays `#Deleted` in every field of the new entry. Closing and re-opening the table will display the new entry correctly. How can I prevent this unusual behaviour, so that after new entries are inserted they display normally without needing to close and re-open the table?

**Steps to reproduce**

Create the following table in `example.sqlite`.

```sql
create table example (
id integer primary key,
sample_type text
);
```

Create a linked table using the SQLite ODBC driver and try to insert values into the "sample_type" column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the type of the `text` column to use a [data type supported by ODBC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/appendixes/sql-data-types?view=sql-server-2017) such as `varchar(255)`. For example this schema doesn't produce `#Deleted` values:

```sql
create table example (
id integer primary key,
sample_type varchar(255)
);
```

This problem happened because SQLite [allows values with multiple different types to be inserted into the same column](https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html), whereas MS Access is very strict about knowing in advance the exact type of data which will be inserted into a column. The ODBC driver therefore has to figure out what type a column should be. This works well if your schema uses an ODBC data type, but if you create a column with a non-specific column type like `text` the ODBC driver has to guess what type the column should be. It appears incorrect guesses might have caused the `#Deleted` values.